# Rotating bitmaps in runtime vs having rotated bitmaps as resources in disk

Tags: android, image-processing

I am developing an android application. I have a custom view which is a functional circular progress bar. It has 12 circles uniformly distributed over a bigger circle.

Since the design is simple and geometric I can achieve the desired results by having a one small circle and rotate it around the center. That will cost me one file on disk, one bitmap on memory - which is kinda small, around 300kb on memory- and some amount of cpu power on rotating and drawing the bitmap.

Another option come to my mind is that I can have all 12 images ready on disk, load all of them on memory, and draw the appropriate one each time. This option doesn't have rotating overhead.

Now my question is, which one is more viable/reliable in general, and specifically for android. You can assume 10 fps is more than enough. And if you think it wont make a noticeable difference please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather have 1 image and rotate it at runtime.  That isn't too costly an operation, and loading N bitmaps into memory can take up a bit of memory, which apps are already hurting for.

Answer (score 0):

In general. I prefer having minimizing my resources as much as possible. Rotating a small bitmap like that won't cost too much power and packaging 12 of those (12*300kb) is a considerable increase in app size. However, you have to consider this in relation to your overall app size and requirements. If you need to minimize size, rotate it and if not, load them all into your app.

Comment: They are actually 20 kb each as png files, their decoded size on memory is 300kb. So app size is not an issue.

Comment: Then I would recommend loading them as assets. No cpu/gpu operations and no need to write all that rotating/drawing code.